# Problem with multicolumn

Tags: luatex, tabularx, multicolumn

I'm working on a new environment based on tabularx and using some luatex functions. Actually, I have the following code.

```
\documentclass[10pt,oneside]{article}
\usepackage{luatextra}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{luacode*}
  function fline(value)
    n = value
    tex.print([[\multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{2} \\\cline{2-3}]])
  end
  function nline(input)
    n = n+1
    tex.print(tostring(n),[[ & ]],input,[[ \\\cline{2-3}]])
  end
\end{luacode*}

\newenvironment{calc}[3][A1]{%
\newcolumntype{x}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}%
\newcommand{\fline}{\luaexec{fline(0)}}
\newcommand{\nline}[1]{\luaexec{nline(\luastring{##1})}}
\tabularx{#2}{c#3}\fline}{%
\endtabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{calc}{5cm}{|x|x|}
\nline{a & b}
\nline{c & d}
\end{calc}
```

The problem is that the `\multicolumn{1}{c}{}` in `fline` function generates a `Misplaced \omit` error. I don't really understand why and what kind of code should be working. Thanks for any help about this.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle : the `[[` characters are lua string delimiters so normally tex doesn't see them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\directlua` is expandable but `\luaexec` is defined via

```
> \luacode@execute=\long macro:
#1->\begingroup \escapechar 92 \newlinechar 10 \edef \\{\string \\}\edef ~{\str
ing ~}\let \%=\luacode@percentchar \let \#=\luacode@sharpchar \expandafter \exp
andafter \expandafter \endgroup \luacode@dbg@exec {#1}.
```

so inserts many non expandable tokens before the `\multicolumn`

It is usually easier to use the primitive directly:

```
\documentclass[10pt,oneside]{article}
%%%\usepackage{luatextra}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\directlua{\unexpanded{%
  function fline(value)
    n = value
    tex.print([[\multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{2} \\\cline{2-3}]])
  end
  function nline(input)
    n = n+1
    tex.print(tostring(n),[[ & ]],input,[[ \\\cline{2-3}]])
  end
}}

\newenvironment{calc}[3][A1]{%
\newcolumntype{x}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}%
\newcommand{\fline}{\directlua{fline(0)}}
\newcommand{\nline}[1]{\directlua{nline("\luaescapestring{#1}")}}
\tabularx{#2}{c#3}\fline}{%
\endtabularx}

\begin{document}


\begin{calc}{5cm}{|x|x|}
\nline{a & b}
\nline{c & d}
\end{calc}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that (a) uses `\directlua` instead of `\luaexec` and (b) doesn't use `[[` and `]]` to delimit Lua strings.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{luacode*}
  function fline(value)
    n = tonumber(value)
    tex.print("\\multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \\multicolumn{1}{c}{1} & \\multicolumn{1}{c}{2} \\\\\\cline{2-3}")
  end
  function nline(input)
    n = n+1
    tex.print(tostring(n),"&",input,"\\\\\\cline{2-3}")
  end
\end{luacode*}

\newcolumntype{x}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}%
\newcommand{\fline}{\directlua{fline(0)}}
\newcommand{\nline}[1]{\directlua{nline(\luastring{#1})}}
\newenvironment{calc}[3][A1]{%
   \tabularx{#2}{c#3}
   \fline}{%
   \endtabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{calc}{5cm}{|x|x|}
  \nline{a & b}
  \nline{c & d}
\end{calc}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. Why do not use brackets delimiters ?

Comment: @MB78 - I find it easier to read the Lua code *without* the double brackets. Clearly, this is mostly a matter of personal preference.